# keras - tensorflow uses GPU incorrectly, not using all its memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I have 2 gpu's:

- Quadro K620 dedicated to graphics tasks
- Tesla K40c dedicated for computer needs - computation.

I run a jupyter notebook on anaconda, to perform training of Vgg16 (or even much smaller) net.

The program keeps crushing, like there is not enough memory.

It seems that some confusion between the GPU is created.

running:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Outputs:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 8983326202371681375
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 11239342080
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 16192653343740641175
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 3.5"
]
```

When the process begins, I get in anaconda promt cmd:

```
2020-01-09 15:09:18.540910: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K40c major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.745
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
totalMemory: 11.18GiB freeMemory: 11.07GiB
```

**But when the training starts, I see in the anaconda prompt:**

```
Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 10718 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)
```

**And the training is not working, usually crashing.**
It use to work in the pass, so I don't think its installation problem.
There is also an option that this started after some window update, but not sure.

How can I solve this ?

I also see a warning in anaconda prompt:

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
```

Can this be connected to the issue ?

**Cuda version:** (from: nvcc --version)

```
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:08:12_Central_Daylight_Time_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

In nvidia-smi , I get:

```
| NVIDIA-SMI 441.22       Driver Version: 441.22       CUDA Version: 10.2
```

**Tensorflow version**

```
1.13.1
```

**keras version**

```
2.2.4
```

**Python version**

```
3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: Are you installing the `tensorflow-gpu` package? Issue shouldn't be related to AVX compilation.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What do you mean by "usually crashing"? What's the error? All the outputs look fairly normal.

Comment: yes tensorflow-gpu is installed.

Comment: Looks like the same GPU is used thoughout the process; are you loading all images on memory for the training? it could be the case that your GPU free memory is not enough for the entire set, but as @xdurch0 said more info on the error are needed

Comment: Can you also confirm which version of CUDA, tensorflow and keras you are using?

Comment: I added all version in the question

Comment: I would recommend to use CUDA version 10.0 (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34354, ymodak's first answer may help, and I'd bet it's not expired)